# Multilayer perceptron in Keras weird prediction

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras, time-series, forecasting

I'm using Keras in R to predict financial sequences. I need to train MLP with 2 hidden layers with 40 neurons in each to predict stock prices. The target data consists of stock prices and the train data consists of four lags of that prices.

`input_data` looks like:

```
               price_lag_4 price_lag_3 price_lag_2 price_lag_1  price
    2018-04-13      157.73      161.21      160.28      162.21 161.37
    2018-04-16      161.21      160.28      162.21      161.37 162.60
    2018-04-17      160.28      162.21      161.37      162.60 166.10
    2018-04-18      162.21      161.37      162.60      166.10 166.44
    2018-04-19      161.37      162.60      166.10      166.44 164.91
    2018-04-20      162.60      166.10      166.44      164.91 162.30
```

Further I split data into training and target sets

```
    train_data = input_data["2014::2017",1:4]
    train_targets = input_data["2014::2017",5]
```

and normalize it using min-max normalization

```
    train_data = as.matrix(train_data)
    train_targets = as.matrix(train_targets)

    train_data = (train_data - min(train_data)) / (max(train_data) - 
    min(train_data))
    train_targets = (train_targets - min(train_targets)) / 
    (max(train_targets) - min(train_targets))
```

Then I construct the MLP with 4 neurons in the input layer, 2 hidden layers with 40 neurons in each and one neuron in the output layer. Then I fit it:

```
    validation_split = 0.05
    model = keras_model_sequential() %>%

    layer_dense(units = 40, activation = "relu", input_shape = 
    dim(train_data)[2]) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 40, activation = "relu") %>%  
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "relu")

    model %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_sgd(), loss = "mse", metrics = 
    c("mae"))

    fit(x = train_data, y = train_targets, epochs = 60, batch_size = 32, 
    validation_split = validation_split)
```

fitting has converged:

[image]

```
Trained on 956 samples, validated on 51 samples (batch_size=32, epochs=60)
Final epoch (plot to see history):
           val_loss: 0.0004162
val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0159
               loss: 0.0002706
mean_absolute_error: 0.01215
```

Further to predict I'm using prices in 2018

```
validation_data = input_data["2018",1:4]
tail(validation_data)
           price_lag_4 price_lag_3 price_lag_2 price_lag_1
2018-04-13      157.73      161.21      160.28      162.21
2018-04-16      161.21      160.28      162.21      161.37
2018-04-17      160.28      162.21      161.37      162.60
2018-04-18      162.21      161.37      162.60      166.10
2018-04-19      161.37      162.60      166.10      166.44
2018-04-20      162.60      166.10      166.44      164.91

prediction_sgd = predict(object = model, x = validation_data)

tail(prediction_sgd)
          [,1]
[71,] 147.2574
[72,] 148.6506
[73,] 148.6407
[74,] 149.8874
[75,] 150.8464
[76,] 151.8221
```

predictions are somehow close to the prices

```
validation_targets = prices["2018"]
tail(validation_targets)
         [,1]
2018-04-13 161.37
2018-04-16 162.60
2018-04-17 166.10
2018-04-18 166.44
2018-04-19 164.91
2018-04-20 162.30
```

So, this MLP architecture works somehow, but when I change activation function to `tanh` the model become:

```
   validation_split = 0.05
   model = keras_model_sequential() %>%

   layer_dense(units = 40, activation = "tanh", input_shape = 
   dim(train_data)[2]) %>%
   layer_dense(units = 40, activation = "tanh") %>%  
   layer_dense(units = 1)

   model %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_sgd(), loss = "mse", metrics = 
   c("mae"))

   history = model %>% fit(x = train_data, y = train_targets, epochs = 60, 
   batch_size = 32, validation_split = validation_split)

   Trained on 956 samples, validated on 51 samples (batch_size=32, 
   epochs=60)
   Final epoch (plot to see history):
                  val_loss: 0.0306
   val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1728
                    loss: 0.001923
       mean_absolute_error: 0.0343
```

[image]

And I get weird predictions:

```
    prediction_sgd = predict(object = model, x = validation_data)
    tail(prediction_sgd)
               [,1]
    [71,] 0.9751762
    [72,] 0.9749264
    [73,] 0.9750333
    [74,] 0.9750219
    [75,] 0.9747972
    [76,] 0.9749493
```

When I use `sigmoid` transfer function, I also get weird predictions

Hence, I have following questions:

1) Why the predicted data so weird in the second case? Am I doing something wrong?

2) Do I need to normalize target data, that is `y` input in `fit` function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tanh and sigmoid have an output range of [-1, 1] and [0, 1] respectively. So if y is not in that range, then the network is unable to learn this, because it can not predict those values. It will try to predict as high as the network possibly can, but that is only 1.

Therefore you need to use a function as your final activation which is able to produce values in the range of your desired output, e.g. linear activation or ReLU. This does not apply to intermediate layers though.

Comment: I've tried making the last layer `layer_dense(units = 1)`, by default activation is linear and layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "relu"). Prediction values became near 1.3 or 1.4, so that doesn't work